# Node js MySQL Railway Connection Issues

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to upload my very first web application to railway. The backend is Node.JS, the DB is MySQL. Before making some changes to the backend to reach the DB from Railway, everything was working. Once I made a few changes to the credentials, I started receiving the error below. I have posted my db config file and middleware that I am using for routes. Is anyone able to explain to me what my issue is?

Terminal Error Message:

```
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:203:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:250:12)     
    at Connection._handleFatalError (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:181:10)
    at Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:194:10)
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:207:10)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

DB config file:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'containers-us-xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'railway',
    multipleStatements: true
})
module.exports = db;
```

Routes Middleware:

```
app.use(session({
  key: 'session_cookie_name',
  secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
  store: new SqlDbStore({
  host: 'containers-us-xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx',
  port: 5528,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  database: 'railway',
  }),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie:{
      maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
      secure: false
  }
}));
```

**UPDATE**

After updating the DB file to the following code, I get the error below the updated code...

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql2/promise');
require('dotenv').config();

const db = createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_Host,
    port: process.env.DB_Port,
    user: process.env.DB_User,
    password: process.env.DB_Pass,
    database: process.env.DB_Data,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0
});
```

New error:

```
C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:351
    const localErr = new Error();   
                     ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND containers-us-west-41.railway.app;
    at PromisePool.query (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:351:22)
    at C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\routes\User.js:178:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)  
    at next (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\rdjon\Code\JDT_Buisness_Project\CatchingSouls\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3) {
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: -3008,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: undefined,
  sqlMessage: undefined
}
```

Comment: It's suspicious to me that you are making exactly 1 MySQL database connection. What you likely should be doing is a MySQL connection pool. I wrote some notes for people just starting off with mysql and node and this is covered: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Comment: I now get a different error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue, you must do the following...

I personally had to change my db config file from

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'containers-us-xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'railway',
    multipleStatements: true
})
module.exports = db;
```

to

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql2/promise');
require('dotenv').config();

const db = createPool({
    host: process.env.DB_Host,
    port: process.env.DB_Port,
    user: process.env.DB_User,
    password: process.env.DB_Pass,
    database: process.env.DB_Data,
    waitForConnections: true,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    queueLimit: 0
});
```

Once the changes were made, my router.post needed to be changed from

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {});
```

to

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {});
```

after that, my query need to change from

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM xxxxxxxxxxx WHERE xxxxxxxxxxxxx= ?', [username.toLowerCase()], (err, results) => {
                 if (err) {
                   return res.json({ message: 'An Error Occured!' });
                 }
                 else if (results.length == 0) {
                   return res.json({ loggedIn: false, message: 'Account Does Not Exist or Password Is Incorrect!' });
                 }
                 else if (results.length > 0) {
                   bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, (err, result) => {
                     if (result == true){
                       return res.json({ loggedIn: true, username: username, isAdmin: true });
                     } else {
                       return res.json({ loggedIn: false, message: 'Account Does Not Exist or Password Is Incorrect!' });
                     }
                   });
                 }
               });
```

to

```
try {
    const useLogin = await db.query('SELECT * FROM xxxxxxx WHERE xxxxxxxxx= ?', [username]);
    
    if (useLogin){
      console.log(useLogin);
      bcrypt.compare(password, useLogin[0][0].xxxxxxxxxxx, (err, result) => {
        if (result == true){
          return res.json({ loggedIn: true, username: username });
        } else {
          return res.json({ loggedIn: false, message: 'Account Does Not Exist or Password Is Incorrect!' });
        }
      });
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.json({ message: 'An Error Occured!' });
  }
```